# Can you clip marks to a region based on other marks in Vega-Lite?

Tags: vega-lite, clip

I would like to create a table with circle marks representing the table values, that are clipped to the underlying cell region. Is it possible to implement this behavior in Vega-Lite?

The closest behavior I have found is the "clip" property, which is able to clip the mark to the group, but it is not clear how to specify the group of an individual mark as the underlying table cell.

I have created an example specification ([link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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)), based on the [Heatmap with Labels example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega-lite/layer_text_heatmap). Here is the code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "transform": [
    {
      "aggregate": [{"op": "count", "as": "num_cars"}],
      "groupby": ["Origin", "Cylinders"]
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "Origin", "type": "ordinal"},
    "x": {"field": "Cylinders", "type": "ordinal"}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "width": {"step": 120},
      "mark": {"type": "rect", "fill": "white", "stroke": "gray"}
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "circle", "clip": true},
      "encoding": {
        "size": {
          "field": "num_cars",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": "Count of Records",
          "scale": {"rangeMax": 4000},
          "legend": {"direction": "horizontal"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "align": "right", "dx": 55},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "num_cars", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {
    "axis": {"grid": false, "tickBand": "extent"}
  }
}
```

[Table created with Vega-Lite with circle marks representing the cell values.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c67cl.png)

While the "clip" property is able to truncate the circles as desired around the edge of the visualization region, it is not clear how to group the marks in order to clip based on the cell region.

Comment: Will you consider Vega or do you need VL?

Comment: @DavidBacci I suppose Vega would be okay, but I was hoping for a more straightforward VL solution. I know Vega has group marks, but I'm curious how this will work for grouping the individual rect and circle to get the "clip" region to be recognized appropriately. I can begin exploring the Vega angle, as perhaps this is out of scope for VL.

Comment: Don't forget you can get the compiled Vega from your VL spec and use that as your starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get the desired result using Vega (instead of Vega-Lite) by using a "group" mark. [Here is a link to the Vega specification in the online editor.](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-DEAOgIkwhQ-IzkcLR0FvFYH1qGQbQ0O0QMVIltGQDFSViSgTRsNlKxI+hfX9FkZW-a9QDQ5xU0XbDcKmGY5iIjA4BLLceIopIQGo2j6MY5jbRgBsA04+o2DYFEaF1bdTnObR30ZWoam-ftBzhHcwkcRC1miI1ogsx8Z0RdAIHsBAmG0xdlwA-5tH3S5vygYk9IaQ1bAcPjHigGgoj445fzYf9tyAnwIJAHZ5DobiQCglw6IAdm-ZEkkgg0wgAYgAFigIqAA4kAasSMhoJAACVtLgAAROBoBmHBMHYSRtwKwL4tCwxv1WAbdOG6pyLIJVtFpfD70yVA2VpNkhTZUk8UJYkyVFGlFmWDamU2dkAH42VOtaLtWKVNjZLbaVpEUfEpM71ueq7WV27aQAAbjZZ85nekAgYOgkiRJclvrFYSX3EaU2Tuh6UbmZk3uBz6sYhix0b22kwYWA5MDZNg8jZDq4H2ZQLihmGYR8RHMB+8V6Q-Zkww+kAOLElCxsqtAADZzRkPLxtQU1vwVAAvTLeNBGhlYEwz0GM9YFZgJA3IqnMR0mvjv0wLSdL06Tlso5IkdMszvms7RbPseyTScjJLPqWdtAGDESnyPztwC1x3APBXopcfxOkxI4ZGS1LQHSgYAPh5aANlkARNLGaRaN6CjSNAQZplsW5ZNUqaA8LOK9kWzFDE2aoEGhbRptlb0Eeu9-pZvbYaOhGsb+h90cxpHfqesfXqhgnJ57giXsB0nQfBkSLH7-bDvhk6F+x4nrox+796JtHZ-xkAvs55Gz5J4GwZ1-BgdZwpig5rm6ReXnNn5kBaSFubeOqEZLaFOj6J+PoNhiTkBAdwFhMrZwQCSDQZszKfE+LYdIzghwu3QJhVyTomhaBkBoT0SBXz6UErgsOJ5Ijgk1jhbQo9dbO1of8c8JxBLMOnrreUhQtwRTgN+KEZAVYZhAbbWS8YJFO2MKYcwlgACS4hxBrDQBGeRZgLBkEmAwVEGiCwpnQOMX2blZDEK8OQyha5qFWVoWCOAnCDJMPQGfIioB2FHmcdwtxG9JCYJPMoQRyhDQiKaGI1CEilpdxAN2WR34TDaOUao9RqBNFJMUbo-RaSpbDm0ErQYhDXYIIyFYus-kjxgO8RCLhWsv6SmCjIURMcIw1ViB044ytVBoCEUY3c+xHCFCMF0EpaiymkOsR3EAXjfA+PqU-MSLTUKwEQE6Y2hQInTRkN0tgvTQnCLuBifqVlVYaiMIUM4hwKxsGwJ6IwKgSRoHXMqOA9Q6AxXOr3QiMhbJMHcAAQVgqNHOkkjB-MBZYGKJoiqaIhY4AAQvceBaiqIoL4jsgiIsjRJjOSYi5MwWxbhAM4PIQcQCPNwi8uB7zMCfPcZi+82LAnODES6ex8UGbt20DAS5isJC+E8LSz5FN1BUxpnTBmhQLhAnVmrDWthPLeUcAAFT9q4U2RSk4qyVdpB4KcHQZQAmVOuxttC1Xqk1Fq35spxQcKa6CxUo5gUQfXBoTRXQZCJY7Myxx9jiFOFYbcSAMR4gApS55RIaWdBoIoJFmhtDx29egoAA) **However, it would still be nice to know if this is possible directly in Vega-Lite.**

[image]

The key approach for Vega is to create a group mark the specifies the cell region, with nested marks for the symbols and text, as shown below. To divide the data amongst the cells, you will need to specify the data for the group using a facet, and then draw the data for the text and symbol from that facet (as illustrated).

```
{
  "name": "cellGroup",
  "type": "group",
  "from": {"facet": {"name": "cells", "data": "source_0", "groupby": ["Cylinders", "Origin", "num_cars"]}},
  "encode": {
    "update": {
      "stroke": {"value": "lightgray"},
      "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "Cylinders"},
      "width": {"signal": "max(0.25, bandwidth('x'))"},
      "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "Origin"},
      "height": {"signal": "max(0.25, bandwidth('y'))"},
      "tooltip": {"field": "num_cars"}
    }
  },
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "layer_1_marks",
      "type": "symbol",
      "from": {"data": "cells"},
      "clip": true,
      "style": ["circle"],
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "opacity": {"value": 0.7},
          "fill": {"value": "#4c78a8"},
          "ariaRoleDescription": {"value": "circle"},
          "description": {
            "signal": "\"Cylinders: \" + (isValid(datum[\"Cylinders\"]) ? datum[\"Cylinders\"] : \"\"+datum[\"Cylinders\"]) + \"; Origin: \" + (isValid(datum[\"Origin\"]) ? datum[\"Origin\"] : \"\"+datum[\"Origin\"]) + \"; Count of Records: \" + (format(datum[\"num_cars\"], \"\"))"
          },
          "x": {"value": 60},
          "y": {"value": 12},
          "size": {"scale": "size", "field": "num_cars"},
          "shape": {"value": "circle"},
          "tooltip": {"signal": "datum"}
        }
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the size of the circle marks with the scale encoding.
I think this represents the values in a clearer way.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "width": 700,
  "height": 150,
  "transform": [
    {
      "aggregate": [{"op": "count", "as": "num_cars"}],
      "groupby": ["Origin", "Cylinders"]
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "Origin", "type": "ordinal"},
    "x": {"field": "Cylinders", "type": "ordinal"}
  },
  "layer": [
    {"mark": {"type": "rect", "fill": "aliceblue", "stroke": "silver"}},
    {
      "mark": {"type": "circle"},
      "encoding": {
        "size": {
          "field": "num_cars",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": "Count of Records",
          "scale": {"range": [100, 2500]},
          "legend": {"direction": "horizontal"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "align": "right", "dx": 55},
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "num_cars", "type": "quantitative"}}
    }
  ],
  "config": {"axis": {"grid": false, "tickBand": "extent"}}
}
```